# Insert date into date9

Tags: date, types, proc-sql

Within my PROC SQL snipped I am trying to compare a column of datatype `date9`. to the date `31.12.2015`'. I tried:

```
test_date = '31DEC2015'
```

This returns me the following error:

> ERROR: Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types.

What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "d" to the end of the quoted date value:

test_date = '31DEC2015'd;